# Make a function more generic to work on both sting[] and string

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

Here is a sample code that performs 2 operations on each string from an array:

```
const R       = require( 'ramda' )
const myArray = [ 'one', 'two', 'tree', 'four', 'five' ]

function capitalize( x ) {
    return x.toUpperCase()
}

function removeLastCharacter( x ) {
    return x.slice( 0, -1 )
}

let stringManipulator =  R.map( R.compose( capitalize, removeLastCharacter) )
// => [ 'ON', 'TW', 'TRE', 'FOU', 'FIV' ]
```

How would you make this function more generic still in a functional way, so it will work on array of string, as well as simple string values passe to it ? Right now this only works on array of strings, not strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ramda itself, philosophically, would not create a function like this, always preferring simple functions that do a single thing.

But it's not hard to write one of your own.  Here's one solution, using Ramda's [`cond`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#cond) function:

```
var process = (function() {
  var fn = R.compose(R.toUpper, R.slice(0, -1));
  return R.cond([
    [R.is(Array), R.map(fn)],
    [R.T, fn]
  ]);
}());

process(['one', 'two', 'three']); //=> ['ON', 'TW', 'THRE']
process('foobar'); //=> 'FOOBA'
```

**Update**:

This would probably be simpler with [`ifElse`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#ifElse):

```
var process = (function() {
  var fn = R.compose(R.toUpper, R.slice(0, -1));
  return R.ifElse(R.is(Array), R.map(fn), fn);
}());
```

Comment: Thanks, your answers are always appreciated. So in the case of Ramda way of things, you would prefer 2 separate simple functions, one for array, one for strings ?

Comment: In Ramda itself, yes, and that is my own personal philosophy as well.  But obviously it's your choice for your own code.

Comment: Added simpler version based on `ifElse` rather than `cond`.